# How can I reduce the memory used for perm gen in web-app

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, permgen

I use tomcat7. My web-app contains:

- hibernate
- log4j
- jdom
- upload jar
- mysql driver
- ...

the total of lib is 30 jar files. My hoster says: "*A lot of memory is allocated to the your program(for Perm gen and heap). Please reduce the amount of memory consumed*".

How do I reduce the memory requirements of my program?

How can the reduce the perm gen memory?

please help me.

Comment: One thing - your hoster is not clear whether it is your heap or your perm-gen (or both) that is the problem. Until you've done a memory profiler as John Watts suggests, don't assume that the perm-gen definitely has a problem.

Comment: Just curious. How much memory is a "A lot"?

Comment: I do not know the host but in local host has changed heap size(10mb to 29mb) and perm gen (10mb to 20mb) and classes (2000 to 4500) . i used java VisualVM profiler .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably attach a memory profiler first and see what type of memory is being used and why. [The answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler) list a bunch of profilers you could try.

Heap is all the memory you allocate for storing objects in Java. Every time you use "new" you allocate on the heap and the memory will become garbage collected some time after the last reference to it is cleared. Here are some typical things you might do to reduce heap usage: Switch from an in-memory parsing API to a streaming one, perhaps by using StAX or SAX instead of JDOM. Fix memory leaks or simply longer-than-necessary object retention by cleaning up in a finally block as soon as the object is no longer needed. Optimize SQL queries to make them return only exactly the necessary data to the app, perhaps by adding a max row constraint or a more restrictive where clause. Limit the size of uploads and stream them to temp files on disk instead of keeping them in memory.

Perm gen is "permanent generation". Generally, memory in the perm gen is never freed until the JVM exits. It is mostly used to store loaded classes. So anything you can do to load fewer classes helps here. Here are some ways to load fewer classes: Try not to use multiple versions of the same jars. Try to load jars in the widest context possible, preferring Tomcat's lib directory or a shared lib directory over WEB-INF/lib. Minimize reloading of the webapp because every time you reload a webapp in Tomcat, it doesn't unload the old versions of all classes it simply loads the new ones.

Comment: I fixed memory leaks and  SQL querie is optimize and size of uploads is 512kb . what your mean "you can do to load fewer classes" . how i can do to load fewer classes ? delete my classes! .how attach a memory profiler ?

Comment: The sentences following that comment are ways to load fewer classes. I edited the answer to make that clearer. "How do I attach a profiler?" is a separate question and the answer is different for each profiler. I would recommend picking a profiler first. If you don't know which one to pick, I'd just try any one that is free or has a free demo. YourKit has a 15-day trial.

Comment: thanks . i currently use  jVisualVM(Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin)   . i download yourkit .